# How to use Search functionality in List view

Tags: android

Here I am inserting data to Data Base using Assets.From data base added into list view.Here i want to search the data in list view . Here i am using filter to search data in list view .How to search data in list view . Here i am attaching code.Please help some one .
    Here data is showing in list view . But,searching data in a list view is not working.

// Here Insert Data Into Database using Assets.

```
        public class CurrencyDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {   
            public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
            public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "currencyconverter.sqlite";
            public static final String DB_PATH = "/databases/";
            static Context context;

            public CurrencyDataBase(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                this.context = context;    
            }
            public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {

                InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

                // Path to the just created empty db
                String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

                // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
                File f = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH);
                if (!f.exists())
                    f.mkdir();
                Log.d("DATABASE", "THIS NAME DATABASE IS NOT EXISTS");
                // Open the empty db as the output stream
                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                // Close the streams
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }

            private static String getDatabasePath() {
                return context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            }

            public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
                File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);

                if (!dbFile.exists()) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("DATABASE", "NOT-EXISTS");
                        CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
                        Log.d("DATABASE", "COPYING THE CONTENT DATA");
                        System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
                    }
                }

                return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
                                | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            }
        @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public ArrayList<CountryArrList> getCountyNames() {
                ArrayList<CountryArrList> arrayList = new ArrayList<CountryArrList>();
                String s = "SELECT * FROM currencytable";

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery(s, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        CountryArrList cntryList = new CountryArrList();
                        cntryList.setCountryName(c.getString(1));
                        Log.e("CNRY NAME", "NAME " + c.getString(1));
                        cntryList.setCountryCode(c.getString(2));
                        Log.e("CNRY CODE", "CODE " + c.getString(2));
                        arrayList.add(cntryList);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
                return arrayList;

            }
        }
```

// Here mainActivity

```
                public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
                         {
                    CurrencyDataBase dataBase;
                    ArrayList<CountryArrList> cntryList;
                    CountryDetailsAdapter adapter;
                    ListView listView;
                    private SearchView search_view;
                    EditText textWatcher;
                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
                        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Cntry_Listview);
                        //autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
                        // search_view = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.cntry_listview_search);
                         textWatcher = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextWatcher);
                        dataBase = new CurrencyDataBase(getApplicationContext());
                        dataBase.openDataBase();
                        cntryList = dataBase.getCountyNames();
                        adapter = new CountryDetailsAdapter(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cntryList);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                        //autoComple=(CustomAutoCompleteView)findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);
                        //autoComple.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(this));

                        textWatcher.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                    int count) {
                                Log.e("onTextChanged", "onTextChanged"+s);
                                //String string=textWatcher.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                    int after) {
                                Log.e("beforeTextChanged", "beforeTextChanged"+s);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                Log.e("afterTextChanged", "afterTextChanged"+s);
                            }
                        });
                    }    
                }
```

// CountryDetailsAdapter Adapter

```
              public class CountryDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryArrList> implements Filterable  {
                            ArrayList<CountryArrList> cntryList;
                            ArrayList<CountryArrList> serachList;
                            Context context;

                            public CountryDetailsAdapter(Context activity, int simpleListItem1,
                                    ArrayList<CountryArrList> cntryList) {
                                super(activity, simpleListItem1, cntryList);
                                this.serachList=cntryList;
                                this.cntryList = cntryList;
                                this.context = activity;
                            }

                            public class ViewHolder {
                                TextView cntry_name, cntry_code;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                ViewHolder holder = null;
                                CountryArrList cntryList1 = getItem(position);
                                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                if (convertView == null) {
                                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                                    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_cntry_adapter,
                                            parent, false);
                                    holder.cntry_name = (TextView) convertView
                                            .findViewById(R.id.adapter_cntry_name);
                                    holder.cntry_code = (TextView) convertView
                                            .findViewById(R.id.adapter_cntry_code);
                                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                                }
                                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                                for (int i = 0; i < cntryList1.countryCode.length(); i++) {
                                    if (position % 2 == 0) {
                                        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2691D7"));
                                    } else {
                                        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#005D9A"));
                                    }
                                    holder.cntry_name.setText(cntryList1.getCountryName());
                                    holder.cntry_code.setText(cntryList1.getCountryCode());
                                }

                                return convertView;
                            }
                            public Filter geFilter()
                            {
                                Filter f=new Filter()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                                        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
                                        ArrayList<CountryArrList> filterdArrList=new ArrayList<CountryArrList>();
                                        if(serachList==null)
                                        {
                                            serachList=new ArrayList<CountryArrList>(cntryList);
                                        }
                                        if(constraint == null||constraint.length()==0)
                                        {
                                            results.count=serachList.size();
                                            results.values=serachList;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            constraint=constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                                            for(int i=0;i<serachList.size();i++)
                                            {
                                                String data=serachList.get(i).countryName;
                                                if(data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))
                                                {
                                                filterdArrList.add(new CountryArrList(serachList.get(i).countryName, serachList.get(i).countryCode));
                                                }
                                            }
                                            results.count=filterdArrList.size();
                                            results.values=filterdArrList;
                                        }
                                        return results; 
                                    }

                                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                    @Override
                                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                            FilterResults results) {
                                        serachList=(ArrayList<CountryArrList>)results.values;
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }

                                };
                                return f;                               
                            }
```

//Country class
                package com.example.currencyconverter;

```
            public class CountryArrList {
                String countryName;
                String countryCode;
                public CountryArrList(String name, String code) {
                    this.countryName = name;
                    this.countryCode = code;
                }

                public CountryArrList() {
                }

                public String getCountryName() {
                    return countryName;
                }

                public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
                    this.countryName = countryName;
                }

                public String getCountryCode() {
                    return countryCode;
                }

                public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
                    this.countryCode = countryCode;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement Search functionality, you need change your adapter.
Add following ArrayList object to your adapter and initialize it in the constructor as it written below.

```
private ArrayList<CountryArrList> arraylist;

public CountryDetailsAdapter(Context activity, int simpleListItem1, ArrayList<CountryArrList> cntryList) {
               super(activity, simpleListItem1,cntryList);
               ...
               arraylist=new ArrayList<>();
               arraylist.addAll(cntryList);
}
```

Now Add the Following filter method to your Adapter class.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        cntryList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            cntryList.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (CountryArrList countryArrItem : cntryList) {
                if (countryArrItem.getCountryName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    cntryList.add(countryArrItem);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

To Search it from the listview, Add the EditText in the view. And apply the below code to that EditText to search from the ListView and also display searched result in the ListView.

```
 etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = etSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                CountryDetailsAdapter.filter(text);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Dhuma1981,it's  not working .Here cntryList is local variable.why we use instead of arrayList.Here cntryList is not working in my code.please reply i am struck here.

Comment: Where you are facing problem exactly?

Comment: when i enter text in search .it's not working.I mean its not showing related data in listview

Comment: Your CountryDetailsAdapter must have been initialized before edittext event got fired.

Comment: Here I am using before CountryDetailsAdapter . please check it above my code once.

Comment: This code will run only when your listview is filled with data and then you want to make a search from it. I hope now it will solve your problem.

Comment: OK..Thanks for replying.I will check once again.